# How can I clear caches on a local Pantheon site?

Tags: drush

I am trying to clear all caches on a local install of Drupal (using pantheon aliases):

```
drush @self cc all
```

However, when the menu caches are cleared I get this error:

```
WD pantheon_apachesolr: Error unable to use client certificate (no key found or wrong pass phrase?) connecting to [error] https://index.live.getpantheon.com/sites/self/environments/dev/index/admin/luke?numTerms=0&wt=json on port 449 Creating default object from empty value Pantheon_Apache_Solr_Service.php:514                                                                                    [warning]WD Apache Solr Views: "0" Status: Request failed
```

The command appears to try to connect to pantheon, but fails. Is there a set up step I might have missed - to cause this error? Or can clearing all caches not be achieved when using a local install alongside the Pantheon platform?

Comment: Try without @self, just `drush cc all`

Comment: Hi awm, good point. Although this still causes the same error.

Comment: Do you have the entire database on your machine? It looks like it has the pantheon_apachesolr module enabled. Try to disable it and try again. `drush dis pantheon_apachesolr -y` then `drush cc all`

Comment: Your specific error message is related to certificates for Pantheon's servers.  It seems that Pantheon support would therefore be a better place to direct this question.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, it does appear the only way to solve this is to disable the mentioned modules. This was echoed from the Pantheon support team.